# gets() not working In first loop iteration but working in subsequent iterations

Tags: c++, string, stl, gets

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
//function to check for substring in a string

int check(const char* str,const char* substring)
{
    char* pos = strstr(str,substring);
    if(pos)
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
}
int main(){
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
    char inp [100000];
    cout<<"Enter String:";
    gets (inp);
    int rec,total=-1;
    puts(inp);
    rec = check(inp,"010");
    total = rec;
    rec = check(inp,"101");
    total = total +rec;
    if(total>0)
        cout<<"GOOD"<<endl;
    if(total==0)
    {
        cout<<"BAD"<<endl;

    }

}
return 0;
}
```

The function is getting called two times for each iteration call from the while loop.In first iteration of while loop, the call to check() function takes place without inputting inp considering it a null string. In further iterations inp is taken from user and everything starts working properly.

Comment: Obligatory: never use `std::gets` in any real program, and preferably forget everything else about it, except that you should never use it. Because any program using `gets` can be trivially crashed (or even exploited, "hacked") by user input. Also, it has been *removed* from the latest C++ standard. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`gets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) reads a line until new line character `\n` is found. Since a new line is still in the input buffer from the previous call to `cin>>t` the next call to `gets()` will see that new line and return without reading anything. You need to call `cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n')` after the call to `cin>>t`.

```
cin>>t;
cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');//this will remove everything up to and including a new line character from the input buffer
while(t--)
{
   ...//your other code
}
```

And on unrelated note, it would be better if you use `getline` to read a line from a stream and `std::string` to accept the input instead of a character array(consider what will happen if the user inputs a string of more than 1000 characters):

```
  #include <string>
  ....
  std::string inp;
  std::getline(cin,inp);//reads a line

  //if you don't want to modify your functions prototypes then you call your check function like
  rec = check(inp.c_str(),"010");//string::c_str() will return a c string
```

but if you don't want to do that at least use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to specify the maximum number of characters to read from the stream like:

```
 fgets(inp,1000,stdin);//will read at most 999 characters from the input stream
```